# Supporting iPad non-retina with retina images only

Tags: ios, ipad, retina-display

I am developing an iPad application and started all my development having in mind the retina resolution (2048x1536).

I named all my images without the @2x suffix.
The app seems to be working fine in the iPad AND the iPad retina simulator.

Do I have to rename all these images to add the @2x suffix and add a copy of all of them without it, and at 1/2 scale?
As I see it some automatic scaling is done by itself.
Is this ok performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine for performance. The big issue, actually, would be memory. It is a waste of memory to display a double-size image when a single-size image will do; after all, we're talking about an image *four* times as large. This might or might not matter depending on how much memory we're talking about. In general you should *always* be scaling images down, *yourself*, to the actual display size/scale at which they are used, whether you do that in code or by supplying multiple versions or whatever. To do otherwise can be a significant memory waste.

Comment: I don't understand the 'shows only for a second or two' part. I am talking about all the images (not splash screen only).

Comment: Sorry, I thought we were talking about launch images.

Comment: I guess the answer still applies. Didn't even think of that.